# Can't Upload Video to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

Using the script below, I am able to upload images in various sizes from 20k to 1.3 megs. However when I try to upload a 15-20 sec video (27 megs), it does not upload. In my web.config file, I increased the max request length to 64 megs.

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="251200" />
  </system.web>
```

I know that large files should be uploaded by using block upload but 27 megs is a small video file. I am using JQuery/AJAX with a generic handler. I do not know if that makes a difference or not

```
        HttpFileCollection hfc = context.Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
            string strFilename = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(trainingfolder);
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = GetBlockBlobReference(strFilename);
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = hpf.ContentType;
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(hpf.InputStream);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a specific error you are hitting when you run above code? Can you get a fiddler trace to see what goes across the wire to storage service?

Comment: No error. Actually by accident, I found that the file does upload. When the progress bar shows 100% complete, if I wait an additional 1 to 2 minutes, the file shows up. Does that have something to do with the file size and Azure Storage? This does not happen when I upload pictures.

Comment: Have you debugged the delay to the storage SDK api call? If not, I would debug that first and see where exactly is this delay introduced (storage SDK or web application) for your video file uploads.

Comment: I debugged the delay. There is a 43 second delay when the file is uploaded and when it shows in the blob storage. I created a test script and uploaded the file to a directory on the VM and it showed up instantly

Comment: Was this resolved? To help debug this further, I would suggest enabling [logging](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/#storage-logging-tools)  - both server and client side logging and looking at logs. Linked article has other ways to help diagnose issues with storage service.

Comment: Yes it is resolved. I put a support ticket with Microsoft. I was told that there maybe a delay especially if the BLOB Storage Server is in another region. Thank you for for assistance Vinay.